# Run application on desktop and display to Smart Tv(s) over LAN

Tags: javafx, lan, smart-tv

Having several smart Tvs (mostly Samsung Tv) connected to the  local LAN network in the office, I want to know if there is any possible way to dispatch my desktop screen to some or all of them. to be more specific it is an application developed with JAVA and JavaFx that I want to be displayed, it require some resources that I can access only from my computer, so sadly developing a native application for smart tvs is not an option.

So what I'am asking for is if there is a programmatic way or an available service providing such capabilities.

Hope I I formulated my issue well enough, and sorry for the bad grammar.

Comment: You can use any screen capture software, and then display resulting video stream on TV.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but what I need exactly is a way to stream to Tv live and almost on real time, the screen capture softwares that I know of, can't do that.

Comment: VLC player can capture screen and retransmit it in RTSP, you can try it.